# Microsoft Office runs on one Admin account but not another

Tags: imac, ms-office, user-account, accounts

Difficult technical issue. I have iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2019) running macOS Monterey version 12.1. The latest version of Microsoft Office was previously running on this admin account but unclear when it stopped working. I have another admin account on the same machine and this admin account runs all Microsoft Office apps. Symptom: Admin account 1: Click on any Office app and Microsoft Error Reporting Window opens with message: There was a problem with Microsoft xxxx (any app gives same error) and we apologize for the inconvenience. Upon clicking on "More Information" a rather large Error Report is generated which starts with Exception: EXC_Crash (SIGABRT) and among many things reports the Crashed module name is merp.
Steps I have taken to resolve:

Removed Microsoft Office with Microsoft level 1 and level 2 technical support assistance. Deleted Microsoft instances from library applications plus all Microsoft instances in Container and Group Container and Cache. 1a. Re-install Office and same error occurs.
Re-set user folder privileges. They were set to: Custom and changed them all to Read/Write, which is what is set for the admin account 2 on which the apps work. Does not fix the issue.
Re-installed the Monterey operating system. Does not fix the issue.
Microsoft says the issue is with the iMac and not Microsoft since it works properly on a different admin account on the same machine (I would tend to agree).

I'd rather not go thru the rather lengthy process of moving all docs and folders from one admin account to the one that works properly. I'd rather find the issue on admin 1.

Any thoughts on a step 4 to resolve this? I can find a way to link to the error report if that is needed. Seems like this should be easy to find since it works flawlessly on one admin account on the same machine, but not another admin account on the same machine.

Comment: Were both Admin accounts created "new" on the system or was one carried over from an earlier system?

Comment: The account on which the Microsoft apps "work properly" was created at the suggestion of Microsoft level 2 support, because the level 2 support suspected that the issue was not Microsoft but was with the older, original user account. So, now they were not both created "new", one was just recently created and that one works.

Comment: Exactly why I asked. So duplicate the data on an external drive, test and then get rid of that old account.

Comment: Yes I realize that is a possibility; however that is hours of work.  Was hoping I could just make this work on the original account.

Comment: Procrastinate all you want, Microsoft told you what to do…

Comment: Thank you so much for your rude and unhelpful comments.  I figured the problem out...needed to reset home folder permissions. Just have to dig a little.  Was hoping someone from this forum might have been down this road...or maybe can help the next person who might have this issue.  Just for the record, Microsoft didn't tell me anything other than...not our problem.